# Windows Authentication with Locust.io?

Tags: python, windows-authentication, locust

I'm trying use Locust.io to load test a project. The project is written in ASP.Net and uses Windows authentication. Is there anyway I can emulate this in my locust script to log a user in?

Answer (score 0):

Locust uses the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library so something like this should work:
https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm